# Sometimes same test scenario not working when doing multiple recordings in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, wiki

I have recorded script for atlassian confluence system. Purpose of this recording is to perform load test on confluence. Below scenarios are recorded

- Login
- Browse a Space
- Create a wiki page
- Edit a wiki page
- Commenting on page
- Logout

I have modified the script and those scenarios are worked fine when i run the script. Then when i record the script again and did the same modifications the edit action is not working as before. I have tried page editing action on multiple environments and sometimes it works and all the time it's not works. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is very high level information that you have shared. Please share more info about what kind error do you get in case of failures. You might be able to trace down your problem & solution by looking into following points.

- Is your login request successful (valid login session)
- Are you using cookie manager
- Have you used assertions to verify valid/invalid responses
- Have you used debug sampler and View Tree Results listener

Please use above to narrow down your problem and then share it over here.